# How to use DefaultHttpClient on Android?

Tags: java, android, connection

[image]I have made an application and used DefaultHttpClient() to access my local server.
The address looks like this: "http://192.168.1.104:8080/login".
I have successfully used it :)
But problem comes when I am in my university and have connected to the network and have an IP address like: "http://130.230.146.148:8080/login", which I am unable to connect and gets the following error:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /130.230.146.148 (port 8080): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host).
Although on my pc I can access "130.230.146.148:8080/".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Move away from HttpClient. It is now deprecated. Use instead [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

The EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host) error means that a TCP attempt to connect was made and failed because the underlying protocol software did not find a network node to connect to the targeting node.

When you say that when you are in the university and trying to connect it means that you are probably within a private sub-net. So what you could possibly do is check if your Android device is also connected to that sub-net.

Comment: yes I am connected to the same network on my Android

Comment: I have also used these two commands:
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),                     android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY, "130.230.146.1");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK, "255.255.254.0");

but still not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at university you are under a proxy server, try to find out what are proxy server IP and port (if you can access to the URL through your pc-browser, you have to have the browser configured for the proxy). Once you have it, try this

```
// Proxy server
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("your host", your proxy); 
// httpClient is your DefaultHttpClient once instantiated 
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
// If you need credentials, ignore otherwise
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(  
            new AuthScope("your host", your proxy),  
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(  
                    "your username", "your password"));
```

Hope helps!

P.D: As others user says HttpClient is deprecated, you may consider move to HttpUrlConnection

Comment: Kindly see my edited post, and could you please tell me how can I extract data from the posted "ipconfig" data

Comment: You can not see the proxy server there, please, open your browser and check if you have any proxy server settings. In Chrome go to Settings -> Configuration, click on 'Show advanced configuration' and go to network and 'Change proxy configuration'. If you have a proxy defined, it will be there.